# Finding the general solution of a DE using substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the substitution $u=y^{-2}$ to find the general solution to the DE: $\\$ $\frac{dy}{dx} + xy + x^3y^3=0$

First, I found what $y$ was in terms of $u$, so
$$y=u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow y'=-\frac{u^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}$$ 
Now plugging this into the DE, we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-xy-x^3y^3=-\frac{u^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}$$
$$xu^{-\frac{1}{2}}+x^3u^{-\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{u^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}u'$$
$$xu^{-\frac{1}{2}}+x^3=\frac{u'}{2}$$
Integrate
$$u=2x^3u+4xu^{\frac{1}{2}}+Cu^{-1}$$
$$1=2x^3+4xu^{-\frac{1}{2}}+Cu^{-2}$$
I am stuck around here, as I don't know if it was right to integrate as early as I did, since it didn't seem to simplify the problem. I tried doing an integrating factor, but I would have gotten a nasty $e^{x^2}$, which would not simplify things. It does not also appear to be separable. Looking for any feedback I can get, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You are supposed to arrive to the point (find your mistake)
$$u'-2x u=2x^3$$

Consider first the homegeneous equation
$$u'-2x u=0 \implies u= ???$$ Then, variation of the parameter.

I am sure that you can do it easily.

Comment: oh jeez thats embarrassing, forgot to divide all the way through. Thank you!